# When using forEach on a ConcurrentHashMap, are updates reflected or does it behave like a failsafe Iterator?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

If I start a [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) action on a ConcurrentHashMap, and other threads are still performing puts on this map, will I see new updates into other bins?

The reason for this is I am trying to find the most effective way to broadcast the contents of a ConcurrentHashMap to listeners, without causing contention to writers of new data to the map. But I want all listeners to receive the same snapshot of the Map when I notify the listeners.

Comment: 90% sure it's going to be the same guarantee as the iterators: [_weak consistency_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly).

Answer (score 3):

[It's not fail safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly), but updates are not reflected in way that you think they are; so if you have already *seen* a bin before you will not get updates from that bin anymore.

If you know how `spread` works internally you can even cause an OOM(this was an excellent comment from a question I've answered from Holger, but I can't seem to find it right now... )

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(500_000_000); 
chm.put(1, 1); 
chm.forEach((key, value) -> chm.put(++value^(value>>>16), value));
```

Comment: This only runs until the capacity is increased, so you need a sufficient initial capacity to let it run to OOME. By the way, you have a typo `cMap`→`chm`.

Answer (score 1):

[The class-level API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) have this to say:

> Retrieval operations (including `get`) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including `put` and `remove`). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.) For aggregate operations such as `putAll` and `clear`, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. ***Similarly, `Iterators`, `Spliterators` and `Enumerations` return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration.***

(Emphasis added.)  That does not explicitly address `forEach()`, but I would expect its behavior to be similar to that achievable via an `Iterator` over the map's entry set.  That is, the `forEach()` iteration would reflect the map's contents as of some fixed point in time.  Therefore, I do not think it at all safe to suppose that modifications to the map by other threads will be seen by the `forEach()`.  I would in fact expect modifications by other threads generally *not* to be reflected in the `forEach()`'s behavior, though there is room in the spec to allow it seeing some modifications.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a snapshot of a map you need to copy the map at a given point. If the iterator would simply be a snapshot, it would have to create a copy initially as well. As that costs extra memory and computation it won't do that, and then there are architectural reasons why that might not be desirable anyways.

> Any non-null result returned from get(key) and related access methods bears a happens-before relation with the associated insertion or update. The result of any bulk operation reflects the composition of these per-element relations

In these lines it is (not so clearly) stated, that any changes that happened before any get (iterator or single call) are already included and reflected by that get operation. So a `forEach` bulk operation will work on the most recent state of the map at any given time.

You already gave the (only) solution to this problem in your question: create a local snap-shot using the copy constructor of the map prior to distribution. It is an extra memory overhead, but that is the only way to get a snapshot.